# How to add !DOCTYPE at top of xml file generated from tinyxml?

Tags: c++, tinyxml

I generated an "my_test.xml" file by making use of tinyxml, till now all has went fine but now i want to validate this against "my_test.dtd" DTD and want to add following line in the starting of "my_test.xml":

```
<!DOCTYPE people SYSTEM "my_test.dtd">
```

Unfortunately, as per http://www.grinninglizard.com/tinyxmldocs/, it looks like TinyXML doesn't support parsing DOCTYPE tags such as the one in the above sample.
What is the recommended or best way to achieve this? I have already spent lot of time in parsing "my_test.xml" and can not even think to go with other parser.So,please suggest me someway by which i can add DOCTYPE tags in order to validate "my_test.xml" against "my_test.dtd".

Comment: what abou adding this tag just as it was text file?

Comment: @Trima i didnt got what you mean..elaborate a bit please

Comment: check it here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19100408/tinyxml-any-way-to-skip-problematic-doctype-tag

Answer (score 2):

I know that this is quite an old post from 2015 but I've just encountered this myself and have a solution  -

```
tinyxml2::XMLUnknown * DocType = xmlDoc.NewUnknown("DOCTYPE sometext SYSTEM \"../myfile.dtd\"");

xmlDoc.InsertEndChild(DocType);
```

Hope this helps someone else.

Comment: This should be the official answer. Because it isn't checked. ChatGPT hasn't learned it! :')